# Can zend framework clear user browser cache?

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework, caching

I want to clear user's browser cached JavaScript files and images in our web site. Can i do it zend `application.ini` setting or other thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add query string at end of the javascript file, that is good option, clearing cookies is not good practice in my opinion. As David said above adding query stings will helpful.

```
www.example.com/js/tooltip.js?version1.0
```

or

```
www.example.com/js/tooltip.js?12-01-2012
```

so browser is going to understand this new files it reloads again, keep it in cache up to next release,and easy to maintainable if you append automatic date at end of the query string.